# update marker location on leaflet while listening to socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, leaflet

Using node.js and socket.io to retrieve users locations in leaflet map markers, every 10 seconds socket.io server emits the coordinates of each connected user, like this:

```
{ username: 'abc',
  lat: 50.5144613,
  lng: 50.2842622,
}
```

in the client side I use:

```
socket.on('new Location', function(data){
         var markers=[];
            var result=JSON.stringify(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);

         if (!markers[obj.username] ) {
            markers[obj.username] = L.marker([obj.lat, obj.lng]).bindPopup(obj.username).addTo(map);
            } else {
            markers[obj.username].setLatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng).setPopupContent(objz.username);
            }
```

this draw a lot of markers for every connected user when client listening to server while I need to update the marker location of each connected user. 
How to update markers positions and not draw more markers?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please feel free to accept it and/or upvote it.

Comment: @peeebeee I tried it and when try to update the marker I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your `markers[]` array is wrong - you're creating a new array every time you receive a location update.

Move `var markers=[]` out of the `socket.on` function.

eg (depending on how the rest of your code is laid out)

```
var markers=[];

socket.on('new Location', function(data){

            var result=JSON.stringify(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);

         if (!markers[obj.username] ) {
            markers[obj.username] = L.marker([obj.lat, obj.lng]).bindPopup(obj.username).addTo(map);
            } else {
            markers[obj.username].setLatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng).setPopupContent(obj.username).update();
            }
});
```

I also added `.update()` so your modified marker updates itself on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly for me. Putting my code here for anybody who wanted to use this with a nested array.

```
//create markers array
var markers=[];
    
//Websocket responses to markers
function onMessage(evt) {
        
var obj = JSON.parse(event.data);
for (var k = 0; k < obj.positions.length; k++) {
            
if (!markers[obj.positions[k].deviceId]) {
markers[obj.positions[k].deviceId] = L.marker([obj.positions[k].latitude, obj.positions[k].longitude]).bindPopup("Device ID: " + obj.positions[k].deviceId).addTo(map);
} else {
markers[obj.positions[k].deviceId].setLatLng(obj.positions[k].latitude, obj.positions[k].longitude).setPopupContent("Device ID: " + obj.positions[k].deviceId).update();
}
}
```

The references (ie. **obj**.**positions**[k].**latitude**) needs to be changed as per your array values.